# Create product after User registration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to create automatically a product after a user registers?

I'm creating a sort of marketplace, so when a user signs up as vendor, I want Woocommerce to automatically create a product with these specs:

Product name = Booking - `the_author_meta ('display_name')`
Product slug = calendar-`the_author_meta ('user_login')`

For example. John Doe registers as vendor with "username: *johndoe*". When the registration is complete, a product is automatically created.

The product name is " Booking - John Doe". The product slug is: "calendar-johndoe".

So the product Booking - John Doe can be found at mysite.com/product/calendar-johndoe

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can achieve this by hooking it to `user_register` because
>   WordPress core handles user registration and runs the
>   [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook right after a user is registered. and to
>   create a product you can use [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) methord to insert post
>   with `post_type = product`

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myCustomProduct', 10, 1 );

function myCustomProduct($user_id)
{
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $display_name = $user_info->display_name;

    $user_full_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', TRUE) . ' ' . get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', TRUE);

    $my_product_name = 'Booking - ' . trim($user_full_name);
    $my_slug = 'calendar-' . str_replace(array(' '), '', strip_tags($display_name));

    $post = array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => "publish",
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($my_product_name),
        'post_name'=> $my_slug,
        'post_parent' => '',
        'post_type' => "product",
    );

    //Create Post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);

    //set Product Category
    //wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Your Category Name ', 'product_cat' );
    //set product type
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_visibility', 'visible');
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', "");
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_manage_stock', "no");
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_backorders', "no");
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', "1");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price', "1");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_purchase_note', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_featured', "no");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_weight', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_length', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_width', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_height', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', "1");
    //update_post_meta($post_id, '_sold_individually', "");
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**The code is tested and fully functional.**

Please Note: *I have assumed that your registration form has `first_name` and `last_name` field otherwise if you are using default WooCommerce registration form then it only has `email` and `password` field, So then above code will generate a product name as `Booking -`*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's awesome! It triggers perfectly and it even assigns the right vendor! I only wonder why it calls every product Booking - admin and slug calendar-admin instead of user credentials. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked because I have't tested the above code. Its all form my WordPress knowledge. 'll test it when I go home and then 'll let you know.

Comment: Yes, I guess it takes admin credentials. I tried to change `$user_info->display_name;` to `$user_info->user_firstname;`  , but still didn't change anything. Still thanks!

Comment: @PaoloMontalto: I have updated my code, actually I hard-coded `user_id` as `get_userdata(1)`  so it was giving admin details, now I fixed the typo error have tested the code as well it is working fine; and if you want to set product category then uncomment `wp_set_object_terms` and replace with you product cat name.

Comment: Actually I did not noticed that it create the product title in this way: Booking - username. So basically for our John Doe with username **jdoe* example it displays the product:

Product name: Booking - jdoe
Product slug: calendar-jdoe

Comment: @PaoloMontalto: I have updated my answer, and pls read the _Please Note_ section.

Comment: Really nice @raunak. Unfortunately I always get "Booking - "(as explained in Please note section) But I'm not using WooCommerce registration form but Gravity Form with User Registration addon. I created a Full Name field and assigned First Name to first_name and Last Name to last_name as you can see from this screenshot: s29.postimg.org/5nxvrpip3/image.png. Still it does not display full name.

Comment: @PaoloMontalto: do you need code to extend WooCommerce default registration form? and I'm not use to Gravity Form so I have to check with that when I'll reach home. but I can help you with WooCommerce registration form.

Comment: Yes sir, I need to stick with the Gravity Form registration. But it's weird since the have the first name and last name field and I applied them to the meta. Still thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello Raunak. I know I shouldn't expect anything from you, but I was wondering whether you found a reason for the full name not display in the product title. Thank you

Comment: @PaoloMontalto: No problem, even I want to know y gravity form did't work, I'll update you on Sunday.

Comment: @PaoloMontalto: can you give me the Gravity Form plugin URL?

Comment: Hi Raunak. If you mean the url where the Gravity Form plugin is stored, it's: http://welpiu.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/ . If you mean the page url where the Gravity Form plugin is located, it's this: https://welpiu.com/diventa-un-esperto/ .

Comment: I need the plugin URL in WordPress repository from where I can download and test the code locally. Are you using a paid version of Gravity Form?

Comment: Yes sir. Maybe this is what you're looking for, even it's just a mirror? https://github.com/wp-premium/gravityforms

Comment: @PaoloMontalto: without licence key it is not allowing me to use it, So sorry I cannot help you. May be this answer can help you if you want to do it by altering WooCommerce form http://stackoverflow.com/a/41290299/5019802