# Wordpress How to get product permalink in php a href link

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm using this line of code to display a button that will link to a specific product create by the author of a page:

```
<a class="button" a href="https://example.com/permalink-<?php the_author_meta('user_login'); ?>"> Take me there <?php the_author_meta('user_firstname')?></a>
```

Everything work fine, but I just need to adjust one think. The "permalink" text is in reality the product permalink the I set in wordpress admin page.

Now in my template I actually put that permalink without php code, and I think that the moment that I will decide to change product permalink to another value, it will take me to a 404 page.

How can I replace the actual permalink name with a php code that is able to find the right permalink no matter how and when I change it?

Thank you!

Comment: you need a product author link for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41223249/5019802?

Comment: do you need product auther permalink or product permalink ?

Comment: I think I explained bad. The existing php part in that link is not the problem. The **permalink** text is `<a class="button" a href="https://example.com/permalink-<?php`. Since my product permalink is now **booking**, in my template I wrote `<a class="button" a href="https://example.com/booking-<?php`. But I guess that if I will change product permalink to another word, it will take me to a 404, since the booking permalink does not exist any more. I neet the link to catch the right product permalink. Hope this clarified