# Create an upload profile picture field in WooCommerce registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this code to add First and Last name to WooCommerce registration: [How to add custom fields to WooCommerce registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580190/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-woocommerce-registration-form/41290299#41290299)

I'm kinda lost on how to add a field for a profile picture upload. I thought I should use one of these functions (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) but it seems I'm looking in the wrong place. Is there a meta for user profile picture?

Comment: Follow process of this link It always works for me. :  
https://claudiosmweb.com/2016/03/24/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-my-account-page/

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: Do you want to add profile picture field on woocommerce registration page?

Comment: @purvik7373 Yes on registration only, not in checkout or cart and it should be as user profile pic

Answer (score 1):

**Use Plugin**

use YITH Woo-commerce plugin that is available with various options.check below link.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-additional-uploads/

**Main features**

- General settings of the YITH WooCommerce Uploads. You can set a
  maximum size for the upload file, one or more file extensions allowed
  and the order status in which you attach a file option will be
  available.
- Allow users to upload a file to the order in the cart page.
- Allow users to upload a file to the order in the checkout page.
- Allow users to upload a file to the order in the order page.

**Add Upload on Registration page:**

You have to code and make plugin.I assume that you aware about a plugin making step.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wdm_upload_image_action', 'wdm_upload_image_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wdm_upload_image_action', 'wdm_upload_image_action_callback' );
function wdm_upload_image_action_callback(){
  check_ajax_referrer( 'wdm-ee4-upload', '_wdmnonce' );
  if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
    //Check if there are any errors in the upload.
    if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0){
      die('An error occurred when uploading.');
    }

    /* validate the file type */

    // check if a file with the same name exists
    if(file_exists('upload/' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])){
      die('File name exists.');
    }

    //get file path
    $filename=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] ;
    $error=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];
    $size=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];

    //Upload Files to WordPress Uploads Folder
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) )
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES[$fileToUpload];
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false, 
                              'test_size' => true,
                              'test_upload' => true,
                              );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    if ( $movefile )
    {
      //file is uploaded successfully
    }
    else
    {
      // upload error 
     }
  }
}
```

If you want to detailed description please refer below link:

https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/5-step-guide-to-add-file-upload-in-ee4-registration-form/

Comment: Look nice, but it doesn't seem to add the field on WooCommerce registration

Comment: Register page. When a user registers via the WooCommerce registration form is supposed to set his own profile picture